# How to make nested text, the second text does not wrap？

Tags: react-native, text

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#docsNav
Description of the official document for nested text, But I want another effect

```
<Text>
  <Text>First part and </Text>
  <Text>second part</Text>
</Text>

// Text container: the text will be inline if the space allowed it
// |First part and second part|

// otherwise, the text will flow as if it was one
// |First part |
// |and second |
// |part       |
```

I want the 'second part' not to wrap
eg:

```
// |First part |
// |and        |
// |second part|
// or
// |First part and       |
// |second part          |
```

Not this：

```
// |First part and second p|
// |art                    |
```

Don't want the 'second part' to be truncated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this don't use nested Text `<Text>{'First part and\nsecond part'}</Text>`